# Cufon + jQuery hover not working

Tags: jquery, css, hover, cufon, jquery-hover

Alright, here's the problem:

I'm building a  [website](http://wilsonbiggs.com/robotics/), utilizing jQuery and Cufon. I'm having a problem with using jQuery's `.hover()` function alongside Cufon. When I hover over the Cufon'd text, nothing happens. The code of importance is:

```
Cufon.replace('div.nav', {hover:'true'});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.nav').each(function() {
        $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).css({
                "text-decoration": "underline;",
            });
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css({
                "text-decoration": "none;",
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="logo" class="nav">
        SLA ROBOTICS
    </div>
    <div id="items">
        <div id="item1" class="navbutton nav">
            <i>members</i>
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="navbutton nav">
            <i>robots</i>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="navbutton nav">
            <i>sponsors</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The rest of the code is visible by viewing the source of the above link. No PHP, so everything's visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cufon is a fine library, but it may not support all features of normal text. Consider using webfonts, generated by [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

Comment: I'd rather use Cufon. I have more control over it and it already has reputation, rather than this website that looks like one of those websites where you download free fonts. `EDIT: It IS one of those websites. xD`

Comment: @WilsonBiggs: Cufon generates `<canvas>` tags that render the fonts. You can't highlight or copy the text. The text is essentially an image.

Comment: No it is not (maybe it has some fonts there, never interested in one, because I have mine to convert). You should upload your own font there and get code, much like with Cufon. The difference is, that it tries different approaches for different browsers.

Comment: @Blender: I know how Cufon works, I just don't know why my code isn't working. It should be, as per the documentation, but it isn't.

Comment: Eh, I ended up using this.